# Confused. How can I grab hold of the returned InputStream?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to fetch some XML and eventually use it as a String. Here's my two methods, the former of which calls the latter.

```
public static void getAllXML(String url) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, URISyntaxException{ 
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser(); 
    parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(url)));  

    XmlUtils.beginDocument(parser,"results");

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    do{
        XmlUtils.nextElement(parser);
        parser.next();
        eventType = parser.getEventType();
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
            Log.d("test",parser.getText());
        }
    } while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) ;       

}

public static InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return  res.getEntity().getContent();

}
```

Then I use a method which takes an `InputStream` and converts it to a `String`. But how do I grab hold of the `InputStream` returned by the `getUrlData` method so I can call `convertStreamToString(myInputStream)`?

Comment: Assuming the code you posted compiles and runs fine, are you able to just do this: InputStream myInputStream = getUrlData(url); convertStreamToString(myInputStream); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `TeeInputStream` ( http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html ) to get the input stream that you pass to a parser and also write the input to a ByteArrayInputStream that you can then use with `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString(String encoding)`.

Something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TeeInputStream is = new TeeInputStream(getDataUrl(...), bytes);
try {
  // Pass is to parser here.
  parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
  // Note: please specify an encoding with InputStreamReader, maybe based on
  // the headers from getDataUrl.  
  ...
} finally {
  is.close();
}

// After parsing finishes, convert the bytes to a String.
String parsed = bytes.toString("UTF-8");
// If UTF-8 is not appropriate, use the encoding specified in headers from URL.
```

Alternatively, you can read the string in first, and then use a `StringReader` with `parser.setInput`.  If your parser is set up to reject large inputs, or can take an `InputStream` as input and does charset detection that you might want to use later, then the approach above is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the stream with java.io API?

Something like :

```
package essai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Reader {

  public static String convertStreamToString (InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    String result = "";

    //Wrap the input stream into a buffered reader so reading is faster and more important, easier with the use of readLine method.
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (currentLine !=null) {
      result+=currentLine;
      currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Of course a you could optimize and a common error in particular would be if your XML is huge with no carriage return, but it should get you started.